# Why do I keep getting this error??? fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an app with sound built in. Whenever I try to build my program I get this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code:

```
var magicSound: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBOutlet var Answer: UILabel!

var AnswerArray = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe", "Try Again", "Not Now", "No Doubt", "Yes Indeed", "Of course", "Definetley Not"]
var chosenAnswer = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let magicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MagicSound", ofType: ".wav")

    do {
        try magicSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL (fileURLWithPath: magicFile!))
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if event?.subtype == motion {
        printAnswer()
        randomAnswer()
        animation()
        showingAnswerAnimation()
        magicSound.play()
    }
}
```

The console throws the error at the line,

```
try magicSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL (fileURLWithPath: magicFile!))
```

If anyone could help me fix my code that would be great.

Comment: MagicSound.wav is not in your bundle?

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Because that's where you have the `!` which means "please crash if this is nil." It's crashing, so that's probably the place.

Comment: So how do I fix it

Comment: @S.Bhatia By learning about Optionals, and what force unwrapping (the `!` operator) actually does. It's covered on [The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: how do I add MagicSound.wav to my bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the line:

```
let magicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MagicSound", ofType: ".wav")
```

should be:

```
let magicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MagicSound", ofType: "wav")
```

The dot character is implicit in to the `type` parameter.
This is how I would write it:

```
if let magicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MagicSound", ofType: "wav") {
    let magicSound = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL (fileURLWithPath: magicFile))
}
else {
    print( "MagicSound.wav does not exist in main bundle" )
}
```

Make sure that the file name is an exact case-sensitive match.Also make sure the resource file is at the top level of the bundle (i.e. in the same folder as the `.xcodeproj` and `.xcworkspace` file).

Comment: I remove the dot from "wav" but the error still managed to pull through, btw the error is thrown at the line I mentioned above

Comment: This is a case where you do want to force-unwrap a value and you do want the app to crash if the file is not found in the app bundle. You want it to crash because it's a problem setting up the app. Once the file is properly added to the app bundle, the app won't crash and there is no need to safely unwrap the path.

Comment: @rmaddy, I understand that, but I prefer not to include forced unwraps in my code, even when the app is not expected to crash. A print statement is a good enough log while debugging, which can be replaced by an error report in production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this ***unexpected found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*** is pretty common errors in SO. You should search more before posting the question.

This `magicFile!` is the main culprit here. The use of `!` means you are unwrapping such a value that you are cent percent sure that the value does contain something other than `nil`. But if the value is `nil` your code is supposed to crash and give you a hint that you're assuming something wrong about the value. So change it.

Now comes the rescue. You have multiple options to safely unwrap an Optional value. Such as `optional-binding`. Having said that you should change your implementation like:

```
if let magicFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"MagicSound" withExtension:"wav") { //As you are supposed to use url, no need to have the path as String
    do {
        try magicSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: magicFile)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is a case where you do want to force-unwrap a value and you do want the app to crash if the file is not found in the app bundle. You want it to crash because it's a problem setting up the app. Once the file is properly added to the app bundle, the app won't crash and there is no need to safely unwrap the path.

Answer (score -1):

Try using below Code hope it helps

```
func playSound() {
 guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MagicSound", withExtension: "wav") else { return }

do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = magicSound else { return }

       player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

and make sure to `import AVFoundation` use this